# OpenCV Radon Checkerboard

Tags: opencv, camera-calibration

Are there any OpenCV camera calibration methods where the target can be larger than the current camera's FoV?

In particular, I use `cv2.findChessboardCornersSB` with the Radon Checkerboard ([openCV calib pattern](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/da/d0d/tutorial_camera_calibration_pattern.html)). I thought it uses the three points in center of the board to determining the board's center. So you the center has to be in the image and not all squares. Therefore we have patterns at the edge of the image resulting in a better distortion model at the boundaries.

Please, tell me if I am right, or if that should not work at all, because I get the checkerboard corner if the full calibration target is in the image, but no corner detection the only the three points are in the image.

Edit:
I use the function find corners as follows:\

```
img = cv2.imread(path)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret, corners = cv2.findChessboardCornersSB(gray, (3,3), cv2.CALIB_CB_LARGER + cv2.CALIB_CB_MARKER)
```

Edit2: 
Full pattern - works.
[image]

Not full pattern - doesn't work
[image]

Thanks

Comment: How do you call `findChessboardCornersSB`? Do you set flag `CALIB_CB_LARGER` or `CALIB_CB_MARKER`?

Comment: Yes, I use them. See edit of the question. So in principle it should work with these two parameters?

Comment: Could you attach a picture of what your camera sees?

Comment: See Edit2: the function used it always the same.

Comment: What is the `patternSize` you use, when only seeing the partial board? Also could you - while debugging - remove the `CALIB_CB_MARKER` flag.

Comment: The `patternSize` remained (14,9). I just changed it (13,6). Then the second image works, but the first one does not work anymore. I test now without `CALIB_CB_MARKER`

Answer (score 2):

Try adding `CALIB_CB_LARGER` and `CALIB_CB_MARKER` to flags when calling `findChessboardCornersSB()`.

According to the [doc](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d9/d0c/group__calib3d.html#gadc5bcb05cb21cf1e50963df26986d7c9), `CALIB_CB_MARKER` means that the pattern must have a marker, and makes calibration more accurate. `CALIB_CB_LARGER` means the detected pattern is allowed to be larger than `patternSize`.

Then, you can set the parameter `patternSize` to the minimum visible size, like 5x6, even if the true size is 10x10 or larger. The pattern will be detected if the marker and 5x6 corners are visible, while corners exceeding the 5x6 zone will also be detected.

As an alternative solution, you can have a look at [ChArUco Boards](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/df/d4a/tutorial_charuco_detection.html).

---

Edit: I tested with your image, `flags` set to `CALIB_CB_MARKER|CALIB_CB_LARGER`, `patternSize` set to 3x3, **color inverted**, then 78 corners are detected:
[image]
It seems that the color of marker is the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. `CALIB_CB_MARKER` and `CALIB_CB_LARGER` are set (I edited the original question about how I call the function). I have set the `patternSize` smaller, but still no corners are detected and on images where the entire target is visible, only as many corners are detected as the `patternSize` is. It seems that the `CALIB_CB_LARGER` flag is not used.

Comment: Thanks that helps a lot. I now detect something on that image too, but only 9 corners, when I set the `patternSize` to 3x3. I seems like `CALIB_CB_LARGER` is not set.

Comment: Check the elements in returned `corners`. `drawChessboardCorners()` can only draw the pattern you set.

Comment: Also `corners` is limited by `patternSize`. So for (3,3) the `len(corners)` is always 9. So it's really the output of `findChessboardCornersSB`. I added the full code on how to read the image and how I use the function in the question above.

Comment: Try adding `corners` to the argument list, i.e. `ret, corners = cv2.findChessboardCornersSB(img_inv, (3,3), corners, cv2.CALIB_CB_LARGER | cv2.CALIB_CB_MARKER)`.

Comment: Or you can call `ret, corners, meta = cv2.findChessboardCornersSBWithMeta(img_inv, (3,3), cv2.CALIB_CB_LARGER | cv2.CALIB_CB_MARKER)`, see API detailds from the opencv doc.